# ERROR: Request for member 'rootview controller' in something not a structure or union?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-sdk-3.2

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Request for member 'rootview controller' in something not a structure or union

what does this error mean?????

Comment: Can you include the code where you have declared window ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly mention iOS SDK 3.0 in your tags. I'm not sure if that's a mistake since the current SDK is 5.0 and nobody should be developing using iOS SDK 3 any more, but assuming it's not a mistake, the rootViewController property of window wasn't added until iOS SDK 4, so maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to set the property `rootViewController` on the object `self.window`, but it can't.  Does `self.window` exist?  What type is it?  My guess is that you've copied and pasted code that's meant to go in the application delegate somewhere else.